# How to write character & in android strings.xml

Tags: android, string, special-characters

I wrote the following in the `strings.xml` file:

```
<string name="game_settings_dragNDropMove_checkBox">Move by Drag&Drop</string>
```

I got the following error:

```
The reference to entity "Drop" must end with the ';' delimiter.
```

How can I write character & in the strings.xml?

Comment: In android studio, you can simply press `Alt+Enter` and it will convert for you.

Answer (score 1177, accepted):

Encode it:

```
&amp;
```

Comment: If using CDATA then be aware that some characters are reserved. © -> &copy;
Refer to this article. http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp

Comment: \u0026   Better to use unicode as suggested by @Moss

Answer (score 170):

For special character I normally use the Unicode definition, for the '&' for example: \u0026 if I am correct. Here is a nice reference page: http://jrgraphix.net/research/unicode_blocks.php?block=0

Comment: This one seems to work the best. The $amp; comes out of getString() without being converted. So it's a pain.

Comment: This didn't work for me for some symbols, like \u227A.

Comment: for Ⓡ symbol use &#174; and trademark ™ symbol &#8482;

Answer (score 85):

This is a my issues, my solution is as following: Use `&gt;` for `>`, `&lt;`for `<` , `&amp;` for `&` ,`"'"` for `'` , `&quot` for `\"\"`

Comment: Cannot edit this because the change is tiny, leaving comment instead.
It should read  `Use &gt; for >, &lt;for <`

Answer (score 28):

Even your question is answered, still i want tell more entities same like this.
These are `html entities`, so in android you will write them like:

Replace below with:

```
& with &amp;
> with &gt;
< with &lt;
" with &quot;, &ldquo; or &rdquo;
' with &apos;, &lsquo; or &rsquo;
} with &#125;
```

Answer (score 10):

It should be like this :

```
<string name="game_settings_dragNDropMove_checkBox">Move by Drag&amp;Drop</string>
```

Answer (score 8):

**&** in string like:

```
<string name="string_abc">Translate &amp; Scan Objects</string>
```

**Output will be:**

Translate & Scan Objects

Answer (score 6):

It is also possible put the contents of your string into a XML CDATA, like Android Studio does for you when you `Extract string resource`

`<string name="game_settings_dragNDropMove_checkBox"><![CDATA[Move by Drag&Drop]]></string>`

Answer (score 4):

This may be very old. But for those whose looking for a quick code.

```
 public String handleEscapeCharacter( String str ) {
    String[] escapeCharacters = { "&gt;", "&lt;", "&amp;", "&quot;", "&apos;" };
    String[] onReadableCharacter = {">", "<", "&", "\"\"", "'"};
    for (int i = 0; i < escapeCharacters.length; i++) {
        str = str.replace(escapeCharacters[i], onReadableCharacter[i]);
    } return str;
 }
```

That handles escape characters, you can add characters and symbols on their respective arrays.

-Cheers

Answer (score 4):

To avoid the error, use extract string:

```
<string name="travels_tours_pvt_ltd"><![CDATA[Travels & Tours (Pvt) Ltd.]]></string>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write in this way

```
<string name="you_me">You &#38; Me<string>
```

**Output:** You & Me

Answer (score 1):

Mac and Android studio users:

Type your char such as  & in the string.xml or layout and choose "Option" and "return" keys.
[Please refer the screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GCoKc.png)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to hardcode the string in xml directly, you can add it up this way.

```xml
  <TextView 
     android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
     android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
     android:layout_centerVertical="true"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="You &amp; Me"
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I've found is to replace the '&' with the Unicode equivalent. So for the example given write:

```
<string name="game_settings_dragNDropMove_checkBox">Move by Drag\u0026Drop</string>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting this because none of the above encodings worked for me.

I found that replacing the ampersand with the sequence: `&#38;`  worked as an xml string resource. As in:

```
<string name="webLink"><a href="https://www.example.com?param1=option1&#38;param2=option2">click here</a></string>
```