# writing some characters like '<' in an xml file

Tags: android, xml, special-characters

since the beginning of my programmation, I used some special character like "<-", ""<<" im my string.xml in Eclipse while developping for Android.

All worked fine for one year, but today, i just wanted to make some minor changes and began to edit my xml files.

I get now compilation error on these characters because eclipse believe it's part of the xml blocks.

Any idea on how I could add this symbol "<" in my xml files?

Thank a lot.

Comment: You mean xml escaping < = &lt; etc.? Or something more complicated?

Answer (score 310, accepted):

Use

`&lt;` for `<`

`&gt;` for `>`

`&amp;` for `&`

Comment: Thank you... I feel stupid because I wal looking for "bigger than" because of my bad english...

After a search on greater than , I found my answer..

Thank a lot btw.

Comment: They're XML character entities. XML doesn't support all of the entities that HTML does.

Comment: what's for $ (dollar sign)?

Answer (score 27):

Another way to insert special character follow [**Moss**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/200898/moss) guide: [How can I write character & in android strings.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3053062) by used [**Unicode definition**](http://jrgraphix.net/research/unicode_blocks.php?block=0):

Example:

```
<string name="item_unknown">\u003c Item Unknown \u003e</string>
```

which present in string :

```
< Item Unknown >
```

Comment: Best answer to solve the problem < and  > on android axml since &lt and &gt still not recognized as valid token

Comment: That solution worked for me much better than above one. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I stumbled upon this question, as I use HTML markup in my strings.

If you refer to the Android [String Resources documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html),
in the section:
"Styling with HTML markup"
you will see that in strings.xml, you need to use &lt; for an opening bracket, but you can safely use backslash and a closing bracket. For example:

```
<b>Text</b>
```

can be written as:

```
&lt;b>Text&lt;/b>
```

in your strings.xml.

If using this HTML string in your code, you can use:

```
Html.fromHtml( getResources().getString(R.string.yourHTMLString )
```

and the output will be your bold string!