# error: Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token) ...?

Tags: android, xml, android-xml

I am working on an application, with following XML. but whenI try to clean/build my project the following error occurs:

"error: Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token)"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<TextView  
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:text="@string/hello";
/>
</LinearLayout>
```

What does it possibly mean?

Comment: In my case was a simple * in the text. Weird tho

Answer (score 47, accepted):

It means there is a compilation error in your XML file, something that shouldn't be there: a spelling mistake/a spurious character/an incorrect namespace.

Your issue is you've got a semicolon that shouldn't be there after this line:

```
  android:text="@string/hello";
```

Comment: @Blundell...O that really was a silly mistake. Thanks, but now i get another prob....have a look at it too bro...!!!

Comment: after removing that semicolon it still shows an error...what could be the problem..??

Comment: Try eclipse>project>clean. The error may still remain as an error in a *different* xml file

Answer (score 50):

I had this problem, and when I had `android:text="< Go back"` it had the correct syntax highlighting, but then I realized it's the `<` symbol that is messing everything up.

Comment: I just changed my text to not have `<`, but I found the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3166967/2423194  which says you can use `&lt;`.

Comment: Can you believe, I had this same problem when i put "<<<Swipe". So nice for you to have added your experience. thanks. appreciated!

Comment: Interestingly, this also happens inside `tools:text` ... Would be nice if Android Studio showed an error!

Answer (score 12):

I had same problem. you can't use left `<` arrow in text property like as `android:text="< Go back"` in your xml file. Remove any `<` arrow  from you xml code.

Hope It will helps you.

Comment: encode it as `&lt;`. The same problem will occur with an ampersand, encode it as `&amp;amp;`

Answer (score 9):

Verify that you don't have any spaces or tabs before

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

also refresh and clean your project in eclipse.

I get this error every now and then and the above suggestions fix the issue 99% of the time

Answer (score 9):

To solve this issue, I pasted my layout into https://www.xmlvalidation.com/, which told me exactly what the error was.  As was the case with other answers, my XML had `<` in a string.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the semicolon after hello

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. In my case, even though I have not understood why, the problem was due to `&` in one of the elements like the following where `a` and `b` are two tokens/words:

```
<s> . . . a & b . . . </s>
```

and to resolve the issue I turned my element's text to the following:

```
<s> . . . a and b . . . </s>
```

I thought it might be the case for some of you. Generally, to make your life easier, just go and read the character at the index mentioned in the error message `(line:..., col:...)` and see what the character is.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I forgot to end my ConstrainLayout

```
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

After that, everything started working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I tried everything on my end and ended up with the following.

I had the first line as:

```
<?xmlversion="1.0"encoding="utf-8"?>
```

And I was missing two spaces there, and it should be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

Before the version and before the encoding there should be a space.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that you are doing **something wrong in XML layout file**

```
android:text=" <- Go Back" // this creates error
android:text="Go Back" // correct way
```