# Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token) andElement type "LinearLayout" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>"

Tags: android, xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
<EditText android:id="@+id/editmessage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/edit_message"
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_conent"
    android:text="@string/button_send"/>

<?xml version"1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<rescources>
    <string android:name="app_name">becreativebuddy</string>
    <string android:name="edit_message">Enter a message</string>
    <string android:name="button_send">Send</string>
    <string android:name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string android:name="title_activity_main">MainActivity</string>
</rescources>


</LinearLayout>
```

Im getting those two errors stated in the title in line 7. I have no idea why it is telling me that i have an idea, because of the fact that I am just learning, so be nice.

Comment: Looks like you forgot a `>` somewhere.

Comment: possible duplicate of [error: Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token) ...?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7089718/error-error-parsing-xml-not-well-formed-invalid-token)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These `Views` here

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"

<EditText android:id="@+id/editmessage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/edit_message"
```

need to be closed. Every `View` needs to be closed at some point with `/>`. The `LinearLayout` is a root `View` so it is being closed at the end with

```
</LinearLayout>
```

so it just needs a `>` at the top

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">
```

The `EditText` is ready to be closed since you are done adding properties to it so add `/>`

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/editmessage"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:hint="@string/edit_message"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't closed off your XML tags properly. Additionally, you need to have your string resources in a separate file in the `/res/values/` folder. Try using:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
<EditText android:id="@+id/editmessage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/edit_message" />
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_conent"
    android:text="@string/button_send"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

And put the following in a new file under `/res/values`:

```
<?xml version"1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<rescources>
    <string android:name="app_name">becreativebuddy</string>
    <string android:name="edit_message">Enter a message</string>
    <string android:name="button_send">Send</string>
    <string android:name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string android:name="title_activity_main">MainActivity</string>
</rescources>
```

Comment: Good spot with the `resources`. I hadn't gotten there yet since the unclosed tags were screaming at me :)

Comment: thank you very much that did the trick, now to sort out other errors