# "LinearLayout" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>" in android

Tags: android, xml

Hi i have a error on my activity i dont know why
error shows in line 6

```
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical"

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="24dp"
    android:text="@string/question_text"
     />
<LinearLayout 
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="horizontal" 
    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/true_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/true_button"
        />
    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/false_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/false_button"
        />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

here is my strings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

<string name="app_name">GeoQuiz</string>
<string name="question_text">Constantinople is the largest city in turkey</string>
<string name="true_button">True</string>
<string name="false_button">False</string>
<string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
</resources>'
```

and here is my other auto generated xml file

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"/>

</menu>
```

this file shows an error on line 5 it says error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'title' with value '@string/action_settings').

So how can I fix this thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16631008/1306419 . Try to extract useful info from there.

Try something like:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">
...
...
</LinearLayout>
```

Note: That when I started the `<LinearLayout` tag, I used `>` at its end. 
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't close your linear layout tag with a >.  So it can't find the end of the first tag.

Comment: oh i forgot paste the last part of my code i had put the layout tag at the end and it still gave me that error

Comment: It might be helpful if you paste the whole Layout file.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you got my first answer.  Try this exactly:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="24dp"
        android:text="@string/question_text"
        />
    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/true_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/true_button"
        />
        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/false_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/false_button"
        />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```