# Adding an ImageView in a custom view

Tags: android, viewgroup

I'm trying to have the `ImageView` appear based on where the user taps in the `GameView`. I'm getting an error on `android:layout_height="300dp"` with the message `"Error:(15) error: not well-formed (invalid token)."` `GameView` extends `ViewGroup`. I have `onMeasure`, `onLayout`, and `onDraw` implemented for `GameView`.

Hovering at the end of these lines shows these error hints:

`<com.example.GameView` -- Multiple root tags

`android:layout_height="300dp"` -- Tag start is not closed

`<ImageView` -- Multiple root tags

`<com.example.GameView>` -- Unexpected tokens

`</LinearLayout>` -- Unexpected tokens

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"

    <com.example.GameView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"

        <ImageView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            />
        </com.example.GameView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Is this your exact layout? The layout contains error in it. Please update your question with the exact layout that you are having.

Comment: Check this question. https://stackoverflow.com/a/7089751/2751547

Comment: Why <ImageView/> put inside <GameView/> ?

Comment: @ReazMurshed Yes, this is the exact layout. I've updated it with the exact errors over hover

Comment: @MeosCoder Depending on where in the `GameView` the user taps, the `ImageView` should show up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
```

You missed `>` of LinearLayout.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a syntax error. com.example.GameView isn't closed properly. Should be like this.

```
 <com.example.GameView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        />
</com.example.GameView>
```

Answer (score 0):

The final layout should look like the following.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.example.GameView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </com.example.GameView>

</LinearLayout>
```