# Whenever I open my android studio and click on run, it doesn't run app

Tags: android

Android resource compilation failed.
Output:

```
C:\Users\i5\AndroidStudioProjects\JustJava\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_main.xml:51: error: not well-formed (invalid token).

Command: C:\Users\i5\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\014c335f30decca3036c4dda871aa0b3\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe compile --legacy \
        -o \
        C:\Users\i5\AndroidStudioProjects\JustJava\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug \
        C:\Users\i5\AndroidStudioProjects\JustJava\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_main.xml
Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows Daemon #4
```

Comment: please send your activity_main layout here.

Comment: It says in the error message activity_main.xml has an error on line 51.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've made a mistake in XML file. This issue can be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/7089751/10698239. If the above link does not give you the solution, give your XML file & additional information is good for others to review your code easily.