# How to write ">" in android studio XML

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

How to write this `>` in the XML.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:text="10 > 5"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="30sp"/>
```

How to write 10 > 5 in android xml

Comment: `android:text="10 > 5"` works just fine

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3166951/7409774

Answer (score 0):

In your java file :

```
textView4.setText("10 > 5");
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your `strings.xml` file

```
<string name="_10_5"><![CDATA[10 > 5]]></string>
```

and use it in xml

```
android:text="@string/_10_5"
```

For more Information about CDATA check [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/w3c/dom/CDATASection.html)

Hope you get the idea