# The reference entity "aana" must end with ';' delimeter?

Tags: android, string

I have a sentence which I need to display and that sentence contain a word &aana..

I have referred this link [How can I write character & in android strings.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3053062/how-can-i-write-character-in-android-strings-xml)  and it gives an answer encode it &amp ..
Can anyone please suggest me how to encode ??

Comment: As an example, to write a sentence `"Hello This is trial & error"`, write it as `"Hello This is a trial &amp; error"`... and in your case, to write `&aana`, write as `&amp;aana`...

Comment: What string exactly you want to show can you show us that full string.

Comment: please add ";" with &amp like &amp;aana

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try this [link](http://coderstoolbox.net/string/#!encoding=xml&action=encode&charset=us_ascii)

```
&amp;anaa
```

should be used in your case.