# Ampersand in app_name not allowed

Tags: android

My strings.xml looks like this:

```
<string name = "app_name>A & B</string>
```

Eclipse is throwing an error: "The entity name must immediately follow the & in the entity reference". What can be the reason?

Comment: <string name = "app_name" formatted="false">A & B</string>

Comment: @Madhur: The error still comes after making the change as suggested by you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I write character & in android strings.xml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3053062/how-can-i-write-character-in-android-strings-xml)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use

```
<string name = "app_name>A &amp; B</string>
```

[Doc reference](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html)

Answer (score 2):

For special character I normally use the Unicode definition,
so for the '&' use  `\u0026`

Or Encoding it to `&amp;`

i.e. Use

```
<string name = "app_name>A &amp; B</string>
```

For more info see this [link](http://jrgraphix.net/research/unicode_blocks.php?block=0)

Answer (score 1):

& is a special character in xml, it indicates start of an entity.So use "&" instead of &(add "amp;" to &)

Answer (score 0):

You must encode the '&' symbol with `&amp;` while you are using it inside XML files.

This should work fine

```
<string name = "app_name>A &amp; B</string>
```