# Android Studio reported out "unescaped or nonterminated entity/reference" when tried to use "and"

Tags: android-studio, binding

Android Studio reported out:

> unescaped or nonterminated entity/reference

When tried to use "and", does anyone know how to fix it?

[image: Error tooltip screenshot]

Answer (score 7):

```
'&' --> '&amp;'

'<' --> '&lt;'

'>' --> '&gt;'
```

Work for me

```
 android:background="@{entry.boolean &amp;&amp; entry.boolean2 ? @drawable/image :@drawable/image2}"
```

Comment: hey do you know the term for this? So that I can look it up later if needed.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that even inside quotation marks, Android is looking for the ampersand (&) to mean something.  To let it know that you REALLY are just using it as text, you have to code it out by entering it as "&" (without the quotation marks - that's just there to show that you have to have all five of those characters).
I got the same error, and as soon as I changed "&" to "&" error went away.  Hope this helps.

Comment: At least, this isn't working when you write in the strings.xml resource file. I know is not the same case, but it's very close. Any ideas @Kevin ?

Comment: Just got the answer in a different post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3053062/how-can-i-write-character-in-android-strings-xml

Actually this is absolutely not related with this issue. Now I see it was an expression, and not a string.