# EditText must not contain the < character

Tags: android, xml, validation

My android app has an EditText field for email where user can give input.

But I'm trying to limit the options for that EditText so the **user** can just enter the allowed characters as email address.
So this is my code

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/sign_up_password_edit_text"
    style="@style/SignUpEditTextStyle"
    android:hint="@string/password"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ 0123456789 !#$%&amp;'*+-/=?^_`{|}~ (),:;@[\]<>"
   />
```

but when trying to compile and run the project I'm getting this error:

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

> Error: The value of attribute "android:digits" associated with an element type "EditText" must not contain the '<' character

How can I fix that and include the '<' character?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3053062/how-can-i-write-character-in-android-strings-xml) will help .

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to encode it like web urls.

In your case: use `&lt;` for '<', `&gt;` for '>'. For more info, take a look at [this](https://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm).

Answer (score 2):

See xml special characters documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97335_02/apps.102/bc4j/developing_bc_projects/obcCustomXml.htm).

Answer (score 2):

escape char on XML,

```
"   &quot;
'   &apos;
<   &lt;
>   &gt;
&   &amp;
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use wizards to customize any string in your XML file, you can use the following special symbols:

Symbol (name)                 Escape Sequence

`<` (less-than)  *********               `&#60;` or `&lt;`

`>` (greater-than) *********              `&#62;` or  `&gt;`

`&` (ampersand)    *********              `&#38;`

`'` (apostrophe or single quote) *********   `&#39;`

`"` (double-quote)  *********                `&#34;`