# How to save entry in strings resources that contains special sign

Tags: android, android-resources

In the below posted entry in the strings.xml, I would like to save a url and it includes & sign. this sign is not recognized...How to save the link as entry in strings.xml..the & sign is not recognized

**url**

```
    <string name="BASE_URL">https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php? 
    action=query&format=json&list=search&srsearch=Trump</string>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I write character & in android strings.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3053062/how-can-i-write-character-in-android-strings-xml)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace each `&` with `&amp;`

```
<string name="BASE_URL">https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php? 
    action=query&amp;format=json&amp;list=search&amp;srsearch=Trump</string>
```

There are some other characters that can be replaced:

```
> -- &gt;
< -- &lt;
" -- &quot;
' -- &apos;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape them, in this case & becomes `&amp;` in the strings.xml file

Answer (score 0):

Replace your **&** with **%26**

So your final URL will become

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query%26format=json%26list=search%26srsearch=Trump
```

**OR**

Enclose your url in double quotes

```
<string name="BASE_URL">"https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=search&srsearch=Trump"</string>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since

> &

is a special character, it has to be replaced with

> %26

This should be your final string as you require it:

```
 <string name="BASE_URL">https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?
    action=query%26format=json%26list=search%26srsearch=Trump</string>
```